# Multiple Dropdown menus with click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have more dropdown menus on a page, and when I click one, how can I hide the other ones which are open?Here is my code:

```
$('nav ul li.sub-menu > a,nav ul li.sub-menu2 > a').click(function(){
    $('.open-menu').toggle();
        $('.active_menu').removeClass('active_menu');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active_menu');
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggleClass('open-menu').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

I tried with the `.open-menu` to add to a dropdown when it's active, and `active_menu` it's just to style the active link.

//Le

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.sub-menu > a').click(function(){
            $('.sub-menu ul').toggleClass('open-menu');
            $(this).parent().find('ul').toggleClass('open-menu');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now it doesn't open the menu that I click on, it opens other menu

Comment: first, try to target only as specifically as required 'nav ul li.sub-menu > a' is overly specific. For instance, I'm guessing you don't have many `<li>` which are not definitely in `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to work like this:

```
$('.sub-menu > a').click(function(){

        if($(this).parent().find('ul').hasClass('open-menu'))
        {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active_menu');
            $(this).parent().find('ul').toggleClass('open-menu');
        }else{
            $('.sub-menu ul.open-menu').toggleClass('open-menu');
            $(this).parent().find('ul').toggleClass('open-menu');
            $('.sub-menu.active_menu').toggleClass('active_menu');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active_menu');
        }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do in this situation is i give all the drop downs a class such as

```
<select name="MyDropDown" class="DropDownGroup" > <option>1</opion> </select>
```

Since all the drop downs have this class its pretty easy to disable all of them except the one you just clicked. Simply do the following

```
$(".DropDownGroup").live("click", function(){
   $(".DropDownGroup").hide();
   $(this).show();
});
```

Now this only covers click as I assumed that is what you wanted but you may need to do it on index change.